# Flutter-The parameter 'email' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, httprequest

I'm new to flutter and I'm working on http post request by creating a model.

```
class LoginResponseModel {
  final String token;
  final String error;

  LoginResponseModel({this.token, this.error});

  factory LoginResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return LoginResponseModel(
      token: json["token"] != null ? json["token"] : "",
      error: json["error"] != null ? json["error"] : "",
    );
  }
}

class LoginRequestModel {
  String email;
  String password;
  String tenant;

  LoginRequestModel({
    this.email,
    this.password,
    this.tenant,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      'email': email.trim(),
      'password': password.trim(),
      'token':tenant.trim(),
    };

    return map;
  }
}
```

I am getting error in the following parts of this code :

```
LoginRequestModel({
    this.email,
    this.password,
    this.tenant,
  });
```

> The parameter 'email' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Then I follow the path below when using this model I created to log in via the login page.

```
LoginRequestModel requestModel;
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
requestModel = LoginRequestModel(email: '', password: '', tenant: ''); //After adding required, I have to enter these fields.
```

and when i send login request via button i see this in debug console.

{email: , password: , token: }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a named parameter, if you don't indicate that it's `required`, then it could be `null`.

Change it to:

```
LoginRequestModel({
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    required this.tenant,
  });
```

Comment: yes, this removes the warning, but even though I enter the program and press the button, the json file in the debug console is as follows: {email: , password: , token: }

Comment: Well, that's a different problem. Show us the code where you instantiate `LoginRequestModel`.

Comment: I edited the question. I'm new to this platform and flutter, sometimes I can mix things up.

Comment: `LoginRequestModel` is not going to magically change if you don't do so. In any case,  you should not have `LoginRequestModel` as a property in your widget at all. To guide you further, I need to see the function you call after clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of `null safety. And you define` String email;` as Nonnull.

To Resolve:

1. if your parameter should not keep null then add the required keyword inside the constructor like below.

```
class LoginRequestModel {
  String email;
  String password;
  String tenant;

  LoginRequestModel({
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    required this.tenant,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      'email': email.trim(),
      'password': password.trim(),
      'token':tenant.trim(),
    };

    return map;
  }
}
```

and

2. If you want your parameters can be null in the future then add the below code.

```
class LoginRequestModel {
  String? email;
  String? password;
  String? tenant;

  LoginRequestModel({
     this.email,
     this.password,
     this.tenant,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      'email': email?.trim(),
      'password': password?.trim(),
      'token':tenant?.trim(),
    };

    return map;
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried both methods, i have to use the model in another dart file like this and
LoginRequestModel=requestModel;
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestModel = LoginRequestModel(email: '', password: '', tenant: ''); //After adding required I change here
  }
the json file in the debug console is as follows: {email: , password: , token: }

Comment: Don't Do `LoginRequestModel(email: '', password: '', tenant: '')`, if you want to give a value to your object do`requestModel.email = "abc@abc.com"`.